# Is there a way to combine elements in an array and place it back into the same array?

Tags: java

I am a beginner in computer science and I am new to everything.
If I have a character array,

```
    char [] c = new char[3];
    c[0] = 'a';
    c[1] = 'b';
    c[2] = '+';
```

Is there a way to combine them and place them into the initial zero position?
To get:
c[] = ['ab+' , 'b', '+']?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have an array of char. Char are single characters (such as 'a', but not 'ab'), so you would have to change it for a string array (many characters in one line). Then you can append the other characters as such :

```
String [] c = {"a", "b", "+"};
for (int i = 1; i < c.length; i++) {
     c[0] += c[i]; 
}
```

In the end, you'll have the output you desired.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not do that.

Look this is a character array. So you can store only one character in a single position.

If you want to put multiple character in a single position, then you should use string array.

Answer (score 1):

The other Answers are correct. The `char` type is for single characters only.

## Classes implementing `CharSequence`

For multiple characters together, use a class that implements [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html) such as the [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html), or the mutable [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and `StringBuffer`.

Here is a diagram I made giving an overview of the text-related classes and interfaces in Java.

[image: Diagram of textual classes and interfaces in Java 8]

## `new String ( char-array )`

The `String` class offers a constructor taking an array of `char` like the one you have.

```
String s = new String( { "a" , "b" , "+" } ) ;
```

## Code points

The `char` type in Java is now obsolete. It cannot represent even half of the 143,859 characters defined in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

Instead, you should be using [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integers to represent individual characters.

```
IntStream codePointsStream = " Hello world.".codePoints();
```

See those numbers.

```
codePointsStream.forEach( System.out::println ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/JtrFDe).

```
128075
127757
32
72
101
108
108
111
32
119
111
114
108
100
46
```

Going the other direction.

```java
int[] codePoints = { 72 , 101 , 108 , 108 , 111 } ;  // Code points for "Hello".
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder() ;
for( int codePoint : codePoints)
{
    sb.appendCodePoint( codePoint ) ;
}
String s = sb.toString() ;
System.out.println( "s: " + s ) ;
```

```
s: Hello
```

Comment: which software did you use for the diagram?

Comment: @dreamcrash [*OmniGraffle*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OmniGraffle) by The Omni Group, for macOS (and iPadOS).

Comment: Thanks, the graphics look great

Comment: @dreamcrash Well, the graphic looks good enough on the original light-theme of this web site. Looks terrible on the new dark-theme. Lesson learned: Always include a background on such graphics.